# Can I clean up the AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases folder?

Tags: azure-functions

I've noticed that this folder has grown up to 1.6Gb of data, it seems to keep there copies of previous releases and I just wonder if I can remove old versions and/or if there's a way to do that automatically.
Those versions have been installed by Visual Studio 2019, I didn't install manually any of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because visual studio will use the latest version to run the function and it won't delete the older version.

And if you use the preview or v3 version function there will be more version folders. You could delete the older version folder only keep the v1,v2 and v3 latest version folder, it will keep working.

And there is another way I get from other comment, you could delete the contents of the folder only keep one version, then copy the the `manifest.json` file to other folders. This way will let all version function tool directs the version you keep.

Like this in the `2.47.1` version folder only has a `manifest.json` point to the `3.4.1` cli. After change this just restart the vs it will work.

[image]

Comment: My latest was 4.3.2 and I just deleted everything older and it seems to be good.  I hope! 6.5 GB of space cleared up!